# How to time delay between each url in a PowerShell http server status check script

Tags: powershell

I am using the following PS script to check the server status of a list of URLs.

```
$linksFilePath = "C:\Temp\urls.txt"
$outCSVPath = "C:\Temp\results.csv"

get-content $linksFilePath |
 Foreach { $uri = $_; try { Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri -Method HEAD -MaximumRedirection 0 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -UseBasicParsing } catch { 
        New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{ Error = $_ } } } |
 Select @{Name="RequestURI";Expression={$uri}}, StatusCode, @{Name="RedirectTo";Expression={$_.Headers["Location"]}}, Error |
 Export-Csv $outCSVPath
```

I want the script to pause for x amount of seconds between each url in my urls.txt list before moving on to the next line and append the results to my results.csv file accordingly.

Is this possible?

Comment: `Start-Sleep 15`, or how ever many seconds you want it to stop for before continuing

Comment: Have a look at [Start-Sleep](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/start-sleep?view=powershell-7.1)

Comment: @AbrahamZinala @Rno Great thanks. So Where should I put the `Start-sleep` command? Inside the Foreach loop after `try` or inside `{ Invoke-WebRequest ...` ?

Comment: Well lets think about this for a second. It really doesn't matter where you put it as long as its in your `Foreach` loop, because you're telling it to do the code that's in your block, each time. So if you place a `Start-Sleep 10` at the beginning of your `Foreach { Start-Sleep 10....`, itll wait before executing the code. Could also be placed in your `Try` block, or at the end of either one

Comment: `Foreach { Start-Sleep 10` causes an error  `Start-Sleep : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'https://www...`

Comment: Also trying `Foreach { $uri = $_; try { Start-Sleep 10 Invoke-WebRequest` causes an error in the results csv for each url saying "A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Invoke-WebRequest".
`

Comment: Solved it. I had to place it at the end of the for loop before the closed bracket `Foreach { $uri = $_; try { Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri -Method HEAD -MaximumRedirection 0 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -UseBasicParsing } catch { 
        New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{ Error = $_ } } Start-Sleep 30 }  |`

Comment: that's because its, its own cmdlet. You are running it in conjunction with your other cmdlets. `Foreach {Start-Sleep 10; $uri = $_;` or,  `try { Start-Sleep 10; `. You're already doing using the semi colon to separate the next command for try, so youd have to do the same with `Start-Sleep`.

Comment: glad it worked tho!